# Prove $((n+1)!)^n < 2!\cdot4!\cdots(2n)!$

Tags: inequality, discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial

so I know I need to prove this via induction, but I am somewhat stuck. Here is what I have does so far.

Let $p(n) = (n+1)!^n \le 2!\cdot4!\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)!$

1. $p(2) = 3!^2\le 2!\cdot4!$
2. Assume $p(n)$ is true.
3. Prove $p(n+1)$
4. $p(n+1) = (n+2)!^{n+1}\le 2!\cdot4!\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n+2)!$

$$\begin{align*}
&=(n+2)!^n\cdot(n+2)!\le\ldots\\
&=(n+1)!^n\cdot(n+2)^n\cdot(n+2)!\le\ldots
\end{align*}$$

Given that $(n+1)!^n\le 2!\cdot4!\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)!$ (Using Inductive Hypothesis)

$$\begin{align*}
&=(n+2)^n\cdot(n+2)!\le(2n+2)!\\\\
&=(n+2)^n\le\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+2)!}
\end{align*}$$

And I am stuck here. Any help anyone can give would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For 4, $p(n+1)$ is a statement, not a term, so should not be set equal to something.  The $=$ should be logical equivalence.  You are trying to prove $p(n) \implies p(n+1)$  This is a nit with your presentation, but is an important concept.

Under 4, you have $(n+1)^n \le \prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i)!$ and want to prove $(n+2)^{n+1} \le \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i)!$.  Dividing them we want to prove $\left(\frac {n+2}{n+1} \right)^n(n+2)\le(2n+2)!$  The first paren on the left is less than $e$ so if you have $n$ large enough you are there.

Comment: I'm confused. Which part is wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you got 2^(n+1)..etc

Comment: When you divide the two products how do you get (2n+2)

Comment: @snowboarder:  It is the leftover term-the one that wasn't there in the previous one.  Note that the upper limit on the product increased by one, so all the terms in the product from $1$ through $n$ divide out, but the $n+1$ term doesn't.  And it has a factorial on it.

Comment: And how about the other side of the equality? How does it become (n+2/n+1)(n+2)

Comment: @snowboarder:  I don't understand the question.  We are given $a \le b$ and want to prove $c \le d$.  If we can prove $\frac ca \le \frac db$ we are there.  That is what I assert in the last sentence.

Comment: Ah I understand. How does it equal e though?

Comment: @snowboarder:  This is from $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=e$ and it approaches from below.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answer but my class is not calc based so.. I am going to need a non limit answer.

Comment: You have a lot of room here.  $\frac {n+2}{n+1} \lt 2$ and there are more than $n$ terms on the right that are at least $2$.

Comment: I guess so. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have reached $ (n+2)^n.(n+2)! < (2n+2)! $ , I will lead you from here.

From this we can observe that there are 'n' number of $(n+2)$ terms on the LHS.

we can easily conclude that:

$(n+2) < (n+3)$ ---> $1st  (n+2)$

$(n+2) < (n+4)$ ---> $2nd  (n+2)$

.......and so on till

$(n+2) < (n+n+2)$ ---> $nth  (n+2)$

So, we can clearly say that $(n+2)^n.(n+2)! < (n+3).(n+4)....(2n+2).(n+2)!$

=>$(n+2)^n.(n+2)! < (2n+2)!$

Hope the answer is clear !

Comment: I'm still slightly confused by your answer.

Comment: @snowboarder: Can you mention which part of my answer is confusing so that i can give a more detailed explanation to that part.